# How long will it take to fill a bath tub with oil compared to water?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, water

As everyone knows, the oil is more viscous than water. But, I've been wondering how long it will take to fill a bath tub compared to water. It is quite obvious that oil will take longer. But, how much longer? If you wondering about what oil I'm talking about, let's say Cooking oil! You are free to make any assumptions about the tap or the pipes. As you know, the flow rate of water and oil would be different under these circumstances. This is not my homework; just my curiosity.

Comment: I think you will need to add some information.  For instance, if the flow rate is specified, then it will take the same amount of time.  If the fluids are dripping out of a small hole in a container, then the oil might actually be faster.

Comment: @ChrisMueller Same flow rate and a typical tap you would find in your bathroom i.e. 3.5 cm hole.

Comment: If the flow rate is the same, by conservation of mass, the time taken to put in a volume $V$ of whatever stuff will be the same. The viscosity will only affect how fast the stuff 'settles' down into equilibrium (i.e. flat surface)

Comment: The question is if the flow rate of oil through a tap would be the same as water - under the same situation. The situation is "filling a bathtub".

eg. typical head of pressure, typical bathroom fittings. Present answer as a ratio.

Does that help you folks out?

Comment: See:
http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/RiverViscosity.htm

You'll also need to do some measuring and look up typical values to get ballpark figures.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are going for slowly-slowly filling the tank, for this you will have streamline flow, reynolds number for streamlined flow is $R_e < 2300$ for comfort and to remove inequality lets take $R_e = 1000$.

Also $ R_e = \frac{\rho v d}{\eta}$. Here $\rho$ is density of liquid, $v$ is velocity of flow , $d$ is diameter of cross section of pipe/tap, $\eta$ is viscosity of liquid.

From the above equation we can compare the velocity of both liquids or anh other pair you want for comparison. Multiplying velocity with area of cross section of tap will give you the rate of flow, then you can just calculate time taken to fill **your** tank by either liquid and compare.

If you do not want to fill slowly-slowly just replace the value of $R_e$ with that of whatever type of flow you are going for !

Answer (score 0):

If the flow rate of the oil and the water is the same (gallons per minute), then they will fill the bathtub in exactly the same amount of time.  You might have to push the oil through harder to get that flow rate, though.

Comment: I think that's what he's asking about "how much harder would you have to push to get the same flow rate?"

Instead of thinking same flow rate, think same pressure difference.